# Linear spaces with the same scalar

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Calculus 2 written by Apostol. On page 38, I came across a sentence.

"Let U, V, W be linear spaces with the same scalars, assume S and T are in L(V,W) and let c be any scalar."

I am wondering what linear spaces with the same scalars mean. Does it mean that they all have real numbers or complex numbers as scalars? Thank you.

Comment: A "vector space over a field" is a collection of objects, called "vectors" with an addition defined, satisfying all the usual rules of addition of numbers, and a "scalar multiplication" where we can combine a "scalar" and a vector, a "scalar" being a member of the field.  It can be shown that every infinite field in which multiiplication is commutative is isomorphic to either the rational numbers, the real numbers, or the complex numbers.  We don't usually use the field of rational numbers, but technically that could be the "underlying field".

Comment: @rason Yes, it could mean that $U,V,W$ all have real numbers as scalars or they all have complex numbers as scalars. The point is that the choice of numbers is the same for every space. Note that there are options besides the real numbers and complex numbers. For instance, we could use finite fields or finite-order extensions of the rational numbers.